# Celery beat fails silently

Tags: celery, celerybeat

I'm having issues with a celery beat worker not sending out tasks to celery. Celery runs on three servers with a RabbitMQ cluster behind HAProxy as a backend.

Celery beat is used to schedule a task every day at 9AM. When I start the worker, usually the first task succeeds, but after that it seems like the following tasks are never sent to rabbitmq. In the celery beat log file (celery beat is run with the `-l debug` option), I see messages such as: `Scheduler: Sending due task my-task (tasks.myTask)`, but no sign of the task being received by any celery worker.

I also tried logging messages in rabbitmq via the rabbitmq_tracing plugin, which only confirmed that the task never reached rabbitmq.
Any idea what could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Axel, is your RabbitMQ cluster in the same host that your app and celery jobs? I'm trying to discard any network filtering issue, like iptables or similar.

Comment: Celery runs on hosts S1, S2, S3 and RabbitMQ on S1, S2 and another host B1. The weird thing is that celery tasks not scheduled by celery beat (i.e., scheduled by the django workers) work correctly.
I don't think it's a network filtering issue, however there might be an issue with the celery beat work not being able to keep the connection open due to HAProxy

Comment: My setup is much simpler and i'm experiencing the same thing. Two servers. One with rabbitmq and one with beat and celery worker. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I find that celerybeat is very unstable. I am almost switching back to cron to send the tasks (assuming that the problem is on the sending side and not on the receiving)